# HTML List Tags - how to give each <li> diffrent color from other?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

how to give each `<li>` different color from other on **Html**

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<ul>
```

so, Iam looking to Display Items as the Following:

Item 1 In red color

item 2 In blue color

item 3 In green color

What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: CSS3 and different classes is the best way to do it.  Decouple styling from content; connect them with JavaScript, jQuery and DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create different classes like this in css

```
   .redText
    {
        color:red;
    }
    .blueText
    {
        color:blue;
    }
    .greenText
    {
        color:green;
    }
```

And then in your html

```
<ul>
<li class = "redText">Item 1</li>
<li class = "blueText" >Item 2</li>
<li class = "greenText">Item 3</li>
<ul>
<ul>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zdwfd3L9/)**

Comment: i used this way because Decouple styling from content; connect them with JavaScript, jQuery and DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Try `style` component for each list.

```
<ul>
<li style="color:red">Item 1</li>
<li style="color:blue">Item 2</li>
<li style="color:green">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i used another solution because Decouple styling from content; connect them with JavaScript, jQuery and DOM manipulation